# Classicmenu indicator revert old icon after update to 0.08

Tags: gnome, indicator, menu, gnome-classic

Today I've updated the super-cool [classicmenu indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) to it's latest 0.08 version.

However I don't like the brand new icon at all. How do I revert it to the previous version? (the white circle based ubuntu logo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classicmenu-indicator has a [configuration option](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/configuration.html#my-icon) for this.

Open a terminal and enter this command:

```
mkdir $HOME/.config/classicmenu-indicator/ && gedit $HOME/.config/classicmenu-indicator/config
```

This will open the text editor with the config file, that is most probably empty.
Copypaste the following lines:

```
[config]
my_icon = start-here
```

Save it, restart the indicator and there you go.